# Adding Labels As subview to UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uilabel

can anyone tell me how to add two labels for a view that i was added on UITableView Cell.i have created that view as UIView with some name.and i have created two labels in UIView class and also set frame for labels,set text and etc.my problem is am getting that view in tableview cell but not those labels.

```
    countLabel.text = @"4";
    countLabel.frame=CGRectMake(275, 10, 20, 15);
    countLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    countLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    countLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    hrsLabel.text = @"Hours";
    hrsLabel.frame=CGRectMake(260, 30, 45, 15);
    hrsLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    hrsLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    hrsLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

this is just i am setting frame,text to labels like that in a UIView.and

```
GreenView *greenView = [[GreenView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 8, 60, 50)];
greenView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.000 green:0.690 blue:0.313 alpha:0.5];
[cell.contentView addSubview:greenView];
```

and here i am adding that UIView to a tableview cell.and i dont know how to add those labels to my UIView. please help me.

sorry if any mistakes in english.
anyone please help me.
thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are adding the labels to the UIView?

Comment: Add these lines,
[self.contentView addSubview: countLabel];
[self.contentView addSubview: hrsLabel];

Comment: Is this code in a seperate cell class?. If so, you need to allocate the labels.

Comment: i just edited my doubt,can you please go through it.

Comment: I think you are doing this in a wrong way (Correct me if I'm wrong). Normally if you wanna add a UIView to a Table Cell, What you do is add  the Labels to a specific view you created in a UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: countLabel.text = @"4";
countLabel.frame=CGRectMake(275, 10, 20, 15);
countLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
countLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
countLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

hrsLabel.text = @"Hours";
hrsLabel.frame=CGRectMake(260, 30, 45, 15);
hrsLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
hrsLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
hrsLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

[self addSubView:countLabel];
[self addSubView:hrsLabel];

Comment: this is what i have done and got it also.@deamonsarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the labels to **GreeView** like this,

Eg:

```
    GreenView *greenView = [[GreenView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 8, 60, 50)];
    greenView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.000 green:0.690 blue:0.313 alpha:0.5];

    countLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 15)];
    countLabel.text = @"4"; 
    countLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0]; 
    countLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    countLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
    [greenView addSubview:countLabel];

    hrsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 45, 15)];
    hrsLabel.text = @"Hours";
    hrsLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0]; 
    hrsLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor]; 
    hrsLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [greenView addSubview:hrsLabel];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:greenView];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i think this is to add label to tableviewCell.i need to add labels on view which is present in tableviewCell..

Answer (score 3):

**create labels like label and label1 and add in UIView**

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 250, 15)];

[label setText:@"Hello"];

UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 250, 15)];

[label1 setText:@"Hello1"];

UIView *myView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];

[myView addSubview:label];
[myView addSubview:label1];
```

Comment: here SubView should be Subview I think

Comment: yeah Thanks joshsverns

Answer (score 2):

```
countLabel.text = @"4";
countLabel.frame=CGRectMake(275, 10, 20, 15);
countLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
countLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
countLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

hrsLabel.text = @"Hours";
hrsLabel.frame=CGRectMake(260, 30, 45, 15);
hrsLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
hrsLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
hrsLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [greenView  addSubview: countLabel];
    [greenView  addSubview: hrsLabel];
    [cell.contentview addSubview:greenView];

    return cell;
```

Comment: yes @Rupesh.i agree with your answer.but i created that view as Objective-C with subclass of UIView.So in .m file am not getting [myView addSubView:] method here i got it now.as i just add like  [self addSubview:countLbl] and thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

```
countLabel.text = @"4";
countLabel.frame=CGRectMake(275, 10, 20, 15);
countLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
countLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
countLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

hrsLabel.text = @"Hours";
hrsLabel.frame=CGRectMake(260, 30, 45, 15);
hrsLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
hrsLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
hrsLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

[self addSubView:countLabel];
[self addSubView:hrsLabel];
```

Finally i Got my answer as above. Thanks alot for all ur replies.